# Adding a CoreData file in Xcode

Tags: ios, core-data

I had previously created a Xcode project involving the retrieving of tweets. I wanted to add CoreData to my project. I already added the necessary information to the AppDelegate, but couldn't find a way to create a new CoreData file to store the entities. Is there something I am missing? [image]

Answer (score 0):

## Follow Below steps for adding core data model

File->new file->CoreData->Model to create a model.

Project->targets-->linked frameworks and libraries Now add a new framework (click on +) 'CoreData'

if you find any issue please let me know... Thanks

Comment: I tried the first part, but when I clicked new file, there was no CoreData type.

Comment: I'll add a picture above.

Comment: as per your screen shot there is four option (ios, watch , tv and mac) >> select ios there is some other category as  source ,user interface, core data etc. >> click on core data and add coredata in your project.

If you find any issue let me know. and can you tell me which xcode version have you using.